# Sort an array with function in it

Tags: c, arrays

There are functions in an array and I wanna sort it, and use the function with the lowest value. I'm trying to make an AI, which is solving the Simon Tatham Sixteen[3x3] game. The functions are operators, and the AI chooseing the operator with the lowest value.

```
int tomb[3][3]={3,4,7,8,1,2,9,5,6};

int cel[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

int heurisztika(int tomb[3][3], int cel[3][3]){
    int i, j, k, l, counter=0, count2=0;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            if(tomb[i][j]!=cel[i][j]){
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            for(k=0;k<3;k++){
                for(l=0;l<3;l++){
                    if(cel[i][j]==tomb[k][l]){
                        if(i==k && j==l){
                            count2=count2+0;
                        }
                        else if(i==k || j==l){
                            count2=count2+1;
                        }
                        else if(i!=k && j!=l){
                            count2=count2+2;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return counter + count2;
}

int Sor1Balra(int tomb[3][3]){  //every function look like this
    int tmp;
    tmp=tomb[0][2];
    tomb[0][2]=tomb[0][0];
    tomb[0][0]=tomb[0][1];
    tomb[0][1]=tmp;

    int ertek=heurisztika(tomb,cel);

    return ertek;
}

int (*operatorok[9])(tomb) = {Sor1Balra, Sor1Jobbra, Sor2Balra, Sor2Jobbra, Sor3Balra, Sor3Jobbra, Oszlop1Fel, Oszlop1Le, Oszlop2Fel, Oszlop2Le, Oszlop3Fel, Oszlop3Le};
```

Comment: What is the value of a function?

Comment: The functions have integer values.

Comment: What value has the `Sor1Balra` function? How to get this "value"? Is it 1? 100? 200?

Comment: @krillin1995 you mean the return type? That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking what's the logic behind the sorting. What is the "lowest value" and why?

Comment: Functions do not have integer values. A function may return an integer value, but what value it returns almost always depends on circumstances (mostly its arguments in good designs, but possibly anything in the program state). To sort, you must pick one value to use as the sort key, such as the value the function returns when passed a particular argument.

Comment: What is `tomb`? Is it meant to be a type or a variable?

Comment: @rtoijala `tomb` must be a type

Comment: If you have a question, please ask it. *I wanna sort it* is not a question.

Comment: Sorry about the poorly made question. I'm a beginner(in programming and on stackoverflow too). I edited the question, I hope it's better now.

Answer (score 4):

you should call `qsort` function from `stdlib.h` like that 
`qsort((void*)arr, size, sizeof(arr[0]), comparator)`
where `arr` is name of array and `comparator` is function which compares two functions. I assume that this functions don't have arguments.

```
typedef int (*myFuncDef)();
int comparator(const void *p, const void *q)  
{ 
    myFuncDef l = *((myFuncDef*)p); 
    myFuncDef r = *((myFuncDef*)q); 
    return (l() - r()); 
}
```

Comment: As OPs function takes an argument of type `tomb` I don't see how `qsort` can be used - at least not directly.

Comment: If he wants to pass arguments than we can create array of structs like 
`struct arg{
   myFuncDef func,
   tomb arg // I don't know what tomb is
};`
and then we should call func with tomb from comparator

Comment: Sorry about the poorly made question. I'm a beginner(in programming and on stackoverflow too). I edited the question, I hope it's better now.

Answer (score 2):

The lowest value of your array functions is the function that *returns* the lowest value.

In order to determine that, your sort function must call each array funcion and see what each two functions return, e.g. like bubble sort but in stead of comparing the array elements it compares the function returns, for example:

```
    if (a[i]() > a[i+1]()) /*swap*/
```

Of course this assumes that the functions will always return the same value.